# Prevent a Terraform resource with for_each from being created depending on a condition

Tags: foreach, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, conditional-operator

I'm using the following resources to create a DynamoDB table with items from a JSON file of objects.

```
module "dynamodb_label" {
  source = "./modules/labels"

  enabled = var.ENABLE_TABLE
  name    = var.dynamodb_name

  context = module.this.context
}

locals {
  json_data               = file("./items.json")
  items                 = jsondecode(local.json_data)
}

module "dynamodb_table" {
  source = "./aws-dynamodb"

  count = var.ENABLE_TABLE ? 1 : 0

  hash_key                      = "schema"
  hash_key_type                 = "S"
  autoscale_write_target        = 50
  autoscale_read_target         = 50
  autoscale_min_read_capacity   = 5
  autoscale_max_read_capacity   = 1000
  autoscale_min_write_capacity  = 5
  autoscale_max_write_capacity  = 1000
  enable_autoscaler             = true
  enable_encryption             = true
  enable_point_in_time_recovery = true
  ttl_enabled                   = false

  dynamodb_attributes = [
    {
      name = "schema"
      type = "S"
    }
  ]

  context = module.dynamodb_label.context
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "dynamodb_table_item" {
  for_each   = var.ENABLE_TABLE ? local.items : {}
  table_name = module.dynamodb_table.table_name
  hash_key   = "schema"
  item       = jsonencode(each.value)

  depends_on = [module.dynamodb_table]

}
```

The JSON file

```json
{
  "Item1": {
    "schema": {
      "S": "https://schema.org/government-documents#id-card"
    },
    "properties": {
      "S": "{\"documentName\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"dateOfBirth\":{\"type\":\"string\"}}"
    }
  },
  "Item2": {
    "schema": {
      "S": "https://schema.org/government-documents#drivers-license"
    },
    "properties": {
      "S": "{\"documentName\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"dateOfBirth\":{\"type\":\"string\"}}"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Error: Inconsistent conditional result types

  on dynamodb-table.tf line 173, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "dynamodb_table_item":
 173:   for_each   = var.ENABLE_TABLE ? local.items : {}
    ├────────────────
    │ local.items is object with 13 attributes
    │ var.ENABLE_TABLE is a bool, known only after apply

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given expressions are object and object, respectively.
```

I've tried many options to pass this error even change the variable type from bool to object. If I remove the condition in `for_each` and just pass `local.items` the `aws_dynamodb_table_item` tries to create regardless of the `depends_on` and it fails of course to create because `table_name` is returned empty because of `count = module.dynamodb_label.enabled ? 1 : 0` in `dynamodb_table` module

I want the `aws_dynamodb_table_item` to be skipped if `var.ENABLE_TABLE` is set to `false`

What am I missing here? Any hint is highly appreciated.

EDIT: Tried the following so far all with same error;

`for_each   = var.ENABLE_TABLE == true ? local.schemas : {}`

`for_each   = var.ENABLE_TABLE ? local.items : {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After experimenting for 2 days around different types of expressions to get around this issue a kind sir on Reddit [referred](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/txqsy2/comment/i3qz52d/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to this solution and it worked like a charm;

`for_each = { for k,v in local.items : k => v if var.ENABLE_TABLE }`

For anyone with a similar requirement this seems a gem that I have missed and recommend you to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "dynamodb_table_item" {
  for_each   = var.ENABLE_TABLE : local.items ? {}
  table_name = module.dynamodb_table.table_name
  hash_key   = "schema"
  item       = jsonencode(local.for_each)

  depends_on = [module.dynamodb_table]

}
```

EDIT: in this case the variable var.ENABLE_TABLE must be boolean.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I have actually tried that and I just updated the question with the error I get. Sorry I didn't mention that already. Please see the second part of the error and the `dynamodb_table_item`

Answer (score 0):

> The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given expressions are object and object, respectively.

I think I found what's the issue is

You should've used jsondecode but used jsonencode instead.

```
locals {
    json_data             = file("./items.json")
    items                 = jsondecode(local.json_data)
}
```

Secondly I run into this issue

```
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 14, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "dynamodb_table_item":
│   14:   item       = each.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 2 attributes
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "item": string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 14, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "dynamodb_table_item":
│   14:   item       = each.value
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 2 attributes
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "item": string required.
```

For that I used this

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "dynamodb_table_item" {
for_each   = var.ENABLE_TABLE ? local.items : {}
table_name = module.dynamodb_table.table_name
hash_key   = "schema"
item       = each.value.properties.S

depends_on = [module.dynamodb_table]

}
```

Hope this helps you debug.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Sorry, I must've mistyped it while creating the question. Its actually `jsondecode` in locals and `jsonencode` when using it in the `item` attribute as `item = jsonencode(each.value)` this is allowing to loop inside the json and create the distinct items. Tried your suggestion but regardless whats in the `item` attribute the `for_each` condition is failing even when it says `The given expressions are object and object` which means its consistent or is it not it seems for some reason that I'm failing to comprehend.